# Calling a method with multiple arguments in AAR from within Unity3D C# script

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, aar

I've got a class with the following method:

```
public static int add( int a, int b ){
    return a + b;
}
```

and I'm trying to call it from Unity Script with

```
var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass( "com.mil.rfcommunitylib.BluetoothClassic" );
int result = ajc.CallStatic<int,int>( "add", new int[] { 1, 2 } );
```

but I get

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
>   at my logcat.

What's wrong? Works with methods without arguments, so we can assume I set up everything correctly.

Comment: From the top of my head: isn't the generic type meant to specify the return type? Shouldn't it be simply: `ajc.CallStatic<int>( "add", new int[] { 1, 2 } );`.

Comment: No, the one with one template argument does not have a return type. Here, the first one is the return type, the second one is the argument type.

Comment: Then it would not match with the signature of your `add` method.
With no return type: `CallStatic(String methodName, object[] args)`, with return type: `CallStatic<returnType>(String methodName, object[] args)`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it match? It's `RetType CallStatic<RetType,T>( string name, T[] args )`, thus `int CallStatic<int,int>( string name, int[] args );` -> should match my Java class, shouldn't it?

Comment: No because it's not `RetType CallStatic<RetType,T>( string name, T[] args )`. But you got the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling:

```
var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass( "com.mil.rfcommunitylib.BluetoothClassic" );
int result = ajc.CallStatic<int,int>( "add", new int[] { 1, 2 } );
```

you should actually use:

```
var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass( "com.mil.rfcommunitylib.BluetoothClassic" );
int result = ajc.CallStatic<int>( "add", 1, 2 );
```

If you look closely in documentation: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic.html) you will see that in your situation your function returns `int` so it should be `javaClass.CallStatic<int>(functionName, params ...)` , and you pass the arguments which the function accept as separate params after the name of the function, not as an array of the same param types.

Comment: Oh. Wasn't aware of the "params" keyword in C#. Makes sense. I thought I'd have to pass an array. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't get why my code doesn't work, I just noticed the method I used (the one specifying _both return and argument type_) does _not_ use the `params` keyword. What would be the intended usage? According to the error message, the wanted signature is `'([I)I'`, which, I suppose, means an int array argument. Is this function merely meant for passing arrays?

Comment: Check your code, your return type is `<int, int>`. I'm even surprised that it compiles... Another thing is that reading the documentation don't get mistaken by `args An array of parameters passed to the method.` That means that you can pass as many params as you need, not that all params should be placed inside an array.

Comment: We're talking about two different methods. The one you mean (one template argument) works the way you posted. The one I used (apparently not found in the Unity online documentation, with _two_ template arguments, first is return type, second is argument type) doesn't. Still not sure how to use it, though. Maybe it's meant for passing arrays. Anyways.